# Crash when deleting an object allocated dynamically in a different function

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator, heap-corruption

I wrote a simple program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;
list<int>& func();

int main(){
    list<int> a = func();
    delete &a;
    std::cout<<"Here\n";
}

list<int>& func(){
    list<int>* ptr = new list<int>;
    return *ptr;
}
```

This program never prints `Here` to the cout stream....

It simply crashes..

I am not able to find the reason..

Comment: @SteveJessop true. Still seems kind of harsh though. If we were to only take titles in consideration, more than half the questions here would be closed/severely downvoted.

Answer (score 6):

I'll assume you mean:

```
list<int> a = func();
```

because otherwise it wouldn't even compile. In any case, the variable `a` was never allocated with `new`. It's a copy of the variable referred to by the return of `func`.

Although you return a reference, you copy it because `a` itself isn't a reference. The following would work:

```
list<int>& a = func();
delete &a;
```

Crashes:  http://ideone.com/T3Iew

Works:    http://ideone.com/ONVKU

Anyway, I hope this is for educational purposes (which is cool, because you get to understand corner-cases), but for production code this would be very **very** wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a declared as a pointer, not a reference. Change `list<int>* a` to `list<int> & a`.

But please don't EVER try to do that sort of thing in production code.